# Django Social Auth - Referring to usersocialauth for foreign key in model

Tags: django, python-social-auth

I'm using the social_django package for the first time. The project only requires authentication for the application through Facebook so I implemented the `SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK` method into my app, which retrieves basic info like username, first name, last name, email address. I also get the user's Facebook profile picture through `SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_EXTRA_DATA`.

I want to figure out how to refer to the `usersocialauth` model as a parent key in my model. Right now, it's associating everything to `auth_user` model, which doesn't allow me to access the Facebook profile picture in the template.

Here is what I am doing at the moment:

models.py

```
from social_django import models as oauth_models

class Review(models.Model):
...
author = models.ForeignKey(oauth_models.USER_MODEL, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I am able to access the basic fields in the template through `<p>{{ review.author.name }}</p>`, but to see the profile picture, I have to do something like this:

```
{% for author in backends.associated %}
  <img src="{{ author.extra_data.picture.data.url }}" alt="">
{% endfor %}
```

I would like to simplify this and just refer to the `usersocialauth` model so I can access all the data from one place in the template.

Answer (score 0):

Found an easier solution.

I can keep ForeignKey relationship with the regular user model and use `author.social_auth.all.0.extra_data.picture.data.url` in the template.